# Issue with changing the precedence order of ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

Tags: ros, build, ros-package-path, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My system: Ubuntu 20.04, ROS noetic.

My issue: I'm working with two packages that have ros1 packages with the same name ORB_SLAM3 which causes an issue with ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and thus with ROS finding the appropriate package to run. The packages I have installed are:

1. https://github.com/VIS4ROB-lab/covins. This package uses ORB-SLAM3 as a frontend and can also run on ROS1. Per the instructions on the page, I have this project installed in ~/ws/covins_ws. [Per the instructions on the section for ROS, I have sourced the file ~/ws/covins_ws/devel/setup.bash](https://github.com/VIS4ROB-lab/covins/blob/master/docs/run_COVINS.md#run_ros).
2. The ORB_SLAM3 package https://github.com/UZ-SLAMLab/ORB_SLAM3, which originally is not a ROS package but offers an option to run on ROS as per [section 7](https://github.com/UZ-SLAMLab/ORB_SLAM3#7-ros-examples).

Where I run into an issue is when trying to build the ROS package for the second package above, specifically at the step `./build_ros.sh` with the following error message:

```
[rosbuild] Building package ORB_SLAM3
[rosbuild] Error from directory check: /opt/ros/noetic/share/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/check_same_directories.py /home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/covins/orb_slam3/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM3 /home/glenn/ORB_SLAM3/Examples_old/ROS/ORB_SLAM3
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/share/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/check_same_directories.py", line 48, in <module>
    raise Exception
Exception
CMake Error at /opt/ros/noetic/share/ros/core/rosbuild/private.cmake:99 (message):
  [rosbuild] rospack found package "ORB_SLAM3" at
  "/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/covins/orb_slam3/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM3", but
  the current directory is
  "/home/glenn/ORB_SLAM3/Examples_old/ROS/ORB_SLAM3".  You should
  double-check your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to ensure that packages are found in the
  correct precedence order.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/noetic/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:177 (_rosbuild_check_package_location)
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (rosbuild_init)
```

The error, as shown above, is because rospack find ORB_SLAM3 returns /home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/covins/orb_slam3/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM3 from package 1 above, even though I want it to find package 2.

**My attempted solution:**

Since I'm not currently using the first package, I choose not to source it (I used to have the line `source ~/ws/covins_ws/devel/setup.bash` in my .bashrc, but commented it out. ). The two lines I have in bashrc are to source my underlay and overlay (`source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash`, followed by `source /home/glenn/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`). Note, there are no ORB_SLAM3 packages in the catkin_ws folder. [Per the instruction from ORB-SLAM3](https://github.com/UZ-SLAMLab/ORB_SLAM3#7-ros-examples), I also add the specfied path to the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable with the command  `export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}:/home/glenn/ORB_SLAM3/Examples_old/ROS/ORB_SLAM3` at the end of my bashrc (side note: the github says ORB_SLAM3/Examples, but the path to build ROS is actually in the Examples_old. I also modified the build script build_ros.sh to account for this).

From here, when I type `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`, the output is:

```
/home/glenn/catkin_ws/src:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/catkin_simple:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/doxygen_catkin:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/eigen_catkin:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/gflags_catkin:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/glog_catkin:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/eigen_checks:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/minkindr/minkindr:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/opencv3_catkin:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/covins/covins_comm:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/covins/orb_slam3/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM3:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/covins/covins_frontend:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/opengv:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/protobuf_catkin:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/suitesparse/suitesparse:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/ceres_catkin:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/yaml_cpp_catkin:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/aslam_cv2/aslam_cv_common:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/aslam_cv2/aslam_cv_cameras:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/robopt_open:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/covins/covins_backend:/opt/ros/noetic/share:/home/glenn/ORB_SLAM3/Examples_old/ROS/ORB_SLAM3
```

where it shows  home/glenn/ORB_SLAM3/Examples_old/ROS/ORB_SLAM3 at the end, after /home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/covins/orb_slam3/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM3, thus it has a lower precedence, and when I type `rospack find ORB_SLAM3`, it returns the latter path.

I then tried adding the path to the first package, after I echo the path to the second package in my bashrc with `export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/covins/orb_slam3/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM3`.

Now, the output of `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` is:

```
/home/glenn/catkin_ws/src:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/catkin_simple:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/doxygen_catkin:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/eigen_catkin:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/gflags_catkin:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/glog_catkin:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/eigen_checks:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/minkindr/minkindr:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/opencv3_catkin:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/covins/covins_comm:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/covins/orb_slam3/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM3:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/covins/covins_frontend:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/opengv:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/protobuf_catkin:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/suitesparse/suitesparse:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/ceres_catkin:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/yaml_cpp_catkin:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/aslam_cv2/aslam_cv_common:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/aslam_cv2/aslam_cv_cameras:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/robopt_open:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/covins/covins_backend:/opt/ros/noetic/share:/home/glenn/ORB_SLAM3/Examples_old/ROS/ORB_SLAM3:/home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/covins/orb_slam3/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM3
```

where it seems the order of precedence is correct. However, when I type `rospack find ORB_SLAM3`, it still returns /home/glenn/ws/covins_ws/src/covins/orb_slam3/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM3 as the path.

Is there any way to fix this? Even when I don't source the setup.bash in the /ws/covins_ws folder, ROS still seems to be able to find this package and I can't get it to find the appropriate ORB_SLAM3 folder. Note, I have already built another ORB_SLAM3 package with a ros wrapper from [here](https://github.com/zang09/ORB_SLAM3_ROS2), but due to some runtime issues with that one, I'm trying to run ROS from the original ORB_SLAM3 package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/417812/issue-with-changing-the-precedence-order-of-ros_package_path/) by [gts_63](https://answers.ros.org/users/75377/gts_63/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2023-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your catkin workspace "remembers" the things you previously sourced. Making it "forget" requires these steps, **in this order**:

- in your `catkin_ws`, delete the top-level `devel` and `build` directories
- source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash # only this one!
- run your `catkin_make` or `catkin build` command
- if the build succeeded, source devel/setup.bash

People also call this "doing a clean build".

Note: in general it's unwise to modify your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH env variable in your ~/.bashrc file, but it is **especially** unwise when the path you are adding is already inside your `catkin_ws` directory.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2023-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gts_63](https://answers.ros.org/users/75377/gts_63/) on 2023-07-30**:
Thank you. I noticed from the ROS wiki that ROS_PACKAGE_PATH doesn't need to be manually updated since catkin was introduced.